# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=VALUES(b) vs. a=b

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a difference between these two at all? I'm working on some code that seems to be using them interchangeably, and a quick test shows me that they seem to do the same things.

```
INSERT INTO...
...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=VALUES(b)
```

vs.

```
INSERT INTO...
...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. they are different. Let's say this would update a row where `b=100`.

```
1. INSERT INTO foo SET a='42', b='69' ON DUP ... SET a=b
2. INSERT INTO foo SET a='42', b='69' ON DUP ... SET a=VALUES(b)
```

(1) will update the row and `a` will become `100`, because that's the value currently in the `b` field for that record.

(2) will update the row and `a` will become `69`, because that's the value provided in the field/value list of the update query itself, regardless of the value in `b` already in the record.

`b` by itself is the field in the already-saved record, `VALUES(b)` is the value that the field would be updated TO if the duplicate error hadn't occured.

Comment: The queries should be `INSERT`, not `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

`a = VALUES(b)` means to get the new value that would have been inserted into the `b` column if there hadn't been a duplicate key, and assign that to the `a` column when updating the row.

`a = b` means to copy the old value of the `b` column to the `a` column in the row that contains the duplicate key.